# 2 consecutive nonblocking assignments

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can someone explain what it means to assign two consecutive nonblocking assignments in a sequential `always` block?

For example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    a <= b <= c;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be more clearly coded as:

```
a <= (c >= b);
```

`a` is assigned the value of the expression "`c` is greater than or equal to `b`".

The 1st `<=` is the nonblocking assignment operator, whereas, the 2nd is the comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

That is not two consecutive nonblocking assignments.

That is `a <= (b<=c);`

`b<=c` evaluates to true (1) or false (0), and that value is assigned to `a`.

Two consecutive nonblocking assignments is not a legal Verilog syntax.